# How to convert a string to a long or another string of ascii values?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

In C++, how do you convert an ASCII string (with no more than 5 elements) to a string of the ASCII values, or a long like below?

```
str = "ABCDE"; --> ascii_value_str = "6566676869";
```

or

```
str = "ABCDE"; --> long_int = 6566676869;
```

Comment: C or C++, please pick  one. These two languages are different.

Comment: Your specification is not entirely concise. Do you need to convert your string and int values back to the initial string value? If so, you need a means to split the result. Easiest solution would be to use the hexadecimal numeral system for your string. And for the int value, shift the result left by 8 bits for each new character added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take each character and cast it to int:

```
int aval = (int) str[i];
```

Now you can turn it into a long through basic multiplication or use the `to_string` function to turn it into a string.

Comment: but make sure that `str` is properly aligned, or it'll generate a segfault. On architectures that allow unaligned access, it's also slower than normal access

Comment: Notice that `int` is generally only 4 bytes long, so it can't store 5-byte values like this. Another thing to care is endianness. Direct convert to string via int would only works if the architecture is big endian

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the string `"ABCDE"` and convert each element to its ascii and add to the string `ascii_value_str`  using `std::to_string`

```
for( const auto& ch: str )
{
  ascii_value_str  +=  std::to_string( (int) ch  );
}
```

For converting to your `long_int`, simply use `std::atol`

```
long int long_int = std::atol( ascii_value_str .c_str() );
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to code if you are using `c++11` because `to_string()` function is available for `c++11` onwards. Now, all you have to do is play with their ASCII Values.

**Look at code snippets :**

1 Convert String into ASCII value string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", output;

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        output += to_string((int)str[i]);
    }

    cout<< output << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

2 Convert the String into ASCII value long int, but mind the range of long int. You might get **wrong** answer for the **long input string**, and now the code is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "xyz";   
    long int output = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(str[i]/100)  {       // three digit ASCII Value
            output = 1000*output + str[i];
        } else if(str[i]/10) {  // two digit ASCII Value
            output = 100*output + str[i];
        } else {                // one digit ASCII Value
            output = 10*output + str[i];
        }

    }

    cout<< output << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ASCII values are in the range 0 .. 127. Your multiplication by 100 is a bug. Use left-shift operator instead: `output = (output << 8) + str[i];`.